# Is this a thin window air conditioning unit?

Tags: windows, air-conditioning

I'm trying to put air conditioning in my master bedroom. It has a loft and hence high ceiling with around 500 sq ft + 350 (loft). It is also on the third floor which is pretty high. As far as I can tell there are 3 options. split a/c, portable unit and window a/c. Split a/c is expensive and portable units probably not good enough/reliable etc. so I'm leaning towards window a/c. Anyway, this is just a background story to what I'm trying to ask.

I happen to see this on my neighbor's window which looks like a window a/c unit. It seems pretty thin but I'm unable to find anything like that anywhere. Could anyone tell me from the picture below if this is a window a/c unit and if so, what could it be? Its at the bottom of the right window that doesn't extend outside much, almost the same level as that of the window.

[image]

Comment: yes, it is funny that I ask this in an internet forum than ask the neighbor!! This is the world we live in.!

Comment: Hard to imagine it's an AC unit unless the bulk of it is on the inside and this is just a vent. There is no room for a compressor in the part shown. It could be the exhaust for a portable unit (compressor on the floor) or even a vent for a dryer or some other device.

Comment: Yea, that's either just a fan of some sort, or a rigged vent for a portable one. All window unites have to have the compressor on the outside of the window (to expel the heat). How long to you plan on living there? If it's 5 years or so, I'd suggest mini-split. They are more expensive, but if you can afford it, they are SO much nicer than maintaining and lugging window units in and out every season and not to mention SO much more quieter.

Comment: ok, thank you for that info. Yeah, i'll be in the house for more than 5 years. I'll look into the mini-split. Do you have any links for a decent one I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a vent for a portable air conditioning unit, and stop looking in my windows!

The other side of it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. i'll try :).. are these any good in your opinion?

Comment: Are what good, portable air conditioners, or window vents for portable air conditioners?

Comment: The portable air conditioners. May be as a temporary solution?

Comment: I've only seen one used once, and in my experience it didn't work well.  It did remove a lot of water from the air (as the collection bin had to be emptied constantly), but it didn't seem to do well at cooling.  They are still available, so they must work for some people in some circumstances. If money wasn't a concern, I'd consider a [ductless split system](http://www.residential.carrier.com/products/ductfree/), instead of a portable air conditioner. If you have a window available, I'd simply use a traditional window unit.

Comment: Thank you. One last question on this. If I go with the window unit, do I have to pull it in, clean it every season? the window is pretty high and probably going to be difficult to do this. Anything available with a filter that can be replaced from the inside?

Comment: Most window units have filters on the inside, but they're only used to filter the air being sucked in from the room. It's probably a good idea to remove the window unit from time to time and inspect it for damage, wear and tear, etc.